# How can I create a dice roller in angular to display different numbers for each dice?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular and Typescript. I want to create a dice roller app but I am unsure on how to create 6 different dice that display a number between 1-6.

I have created the 6 dice which at the moment show a number between 1-6. However the number is the same on each die and I was wondering how I get it to show different numbers. A number can appear more than once on the same roll though. E.g. 3, 5, 1, 3, 6, 6.

I understand that the {{ diceValue }} shown in my HTML below will show the same number because it's set to equal one value and then repeated 6 times. However I am unsure how to go about updating this to display 6 separate values.

```
// HTML 

<div class="diceRoller">
    <div>
        <div class="square">
            <span>{{ diceValue }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <span>{{ diceValue }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <span>{{ diceValue }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <span>{{ diceValue }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <span>{{ diceValue }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <span>{{ diceValue }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="roll-button" (click)="diceRoll()">Roll Dice!</button>
</div>

// Angular: dice-roll.component.ts

export class DiceRollComponent {
    public diceValue: number = 0;

    diceRoll() {
        let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        this.diceValue = randomNum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// HTML 

<div class="diceRoller">
    <div>
        <div class="square" *ngFor="let diceValue of diceValues">
            <span>{{ diceValue }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="roll-button" (click)="diceRoll()">Roll Dice!</button>
</div>

// Angular: dice-roll.component.ts

export class DiceRollComponent {
  public diceValues: Array<number> = [0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0];

  diceRoll() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.diceValues.length; i++) {
      this.diceValues[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    }
  }
}
```